# How do I extract current date, month and year in the format yyyy-mm-dd in karate dsl?

Tags: karate

```
  * def date =
  """
  function(s) {
    var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
    var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    return sdf.parse(s).time;
  }
  """
```

Currently, I'm using this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's a karate chop method? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def today =
  """
  function() {
    var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
    var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    return sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
  }
  """
* print today()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive the following by using javascript as follows:

```
* def todaysDate = 
"""
function()
 {
 var d=new Date();
 var month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
 var day = String(d.getDate());
 var year = String(d.getFullYear());
 if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
 if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
 return year+'/'+month+'/'+day
 }
 """
* print todaysDate()
```